# How to fetch videos from mobile gallery and display them using react-native-video

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-videoview, react-native-video

I'm using [@react-native-community/cameraroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cameraroll) to fetch gallery videos and [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) to display the video.

**Note:** Server video url is working fine but problem occurs only when I try to load video from local gallery .

Working for URL like = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"

Not working for URL like = "file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Animated Gifs/VID-25640119-WA6028.mp4"

Code snippet

```
  import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
  import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
  import CameraRoll from '@react-native-community/cameraroll';
  
const VideoComponent = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  const hasAndroidPermission = async () => {
    const permission = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

    const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(permission);
    if (hasPermission) {
      return true;
    }

    const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(permission);
    return status === 'granted';
  };

  const openVideos = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !(await hasAndroidPermission())) {
      return;
    }
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      assetType: 'Videos',
      first: 10,
    }).then(res => {
      setVideos(res.edges);
      // console.log('videos', videos);
    });
  };

    useEffect(() => {
    openVideos();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}}>
      <Video
            ref={ref => (player = ref)}
             source={{
               uri: videos[0]?.node?.image?.uri,
            // uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'; ----->>> this url is working fine
             }}
            style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}}
            resizeMode="cover"
            repeat={false}
            paused={false}
            controls={true}
          />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, we get : "ph://3C496411-F78E-49A9-AE72-9CE816DD01FE/L0/001" uri.

convert the above 'ph' uri to assets uri by slicing the ph uri

```js
phURI = "ph://61980D0C-E64C-424F-93AB-0382D8789CA8/L0/001";
assetURI= `assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=${phURI.slice(5,41)}&ext=mp4`;
```

**OR**

```js
phURI = "ph://61980D0C-E64C-424F-93AB-0382D8789CA8/L0/001";
uriId = phURI.split('/')[2];
assetURI = `assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=${uriId}&ext=mp4`;
```

Then using assetURI in the source uri we can play the video.